# Параллельное программирование jupyter windows

Tags: python-3.x, qt5, matplotlib, multiprocessing, jupyter-notebook

Задача такая:
Есть некоторая функция `get_data`, которая непрерывно добавляет в датафрейм значения. Чтобы особо не грузить подробностями, опишу функцию, которая просто добавляет по 2 значения из готовых массивов с некоторым временным интервалом

```
%matplotlib qt5
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import time

freqs = np.arange(1, 1000, 1)
currents = np.arange(1, 1000, 1)

frame = pd.DataFrame({'x_value': [],
                     'y_value': []})

x_ind = 0
y_ind = 0

def get_data():
    global x_ind, y_ind, frame
    
    try:   
        while x_ind != len(currents):
            
            new_line = {'x_value': currents[x_ind],
                        'y_value': freqs[y_ind]}
        
            frame = frame.append(new_line, ignore_index=True)
            x_ind += 1
            y_ind += 1

            time.sleep(1)
            
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Есть и 2 функция, которая все это в реальном времени анимирует и обновляет окошко с графиком (Бэкенд matplotlib - qt5) раз в 3 секунды

```
"""Функция для анимации"""
n = 0

def animate(self):
    global n

    x = frame['x_value'].values
    y = frame['y_value'].values
    
    plt.plot(x,y, label=f'{n}')
    plt.legend()
    n += 1 

"""Сама анимация"""
def animation():
    ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=3000)
    plt.show()

    try:
        while len(plt.get_fignums()) > 0:
            plt.pause(0.1)
    except:
        plt.close('all')
```

Мне бы хотелось, чтобы эти 2 функции (`get_data` и `animation`) выполнялись одновременно. Я уже понял, что библиотека Multiprocessing не дружит с юпитером. Пробовал также и библиотеку Multiprocess с конструкцией

```
#! pip install multiprocess
from multiprocess import Process

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Process(target=get_data)
    p2 = Process(target=animation)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

она не сработала. Ячейка просто моментально выполнилась и все.
Далее я начал пробовать библиотеку `ipyparallel`. Установил ее
`conda install ipyparallel`
Активировал кластерное расширение
`ipcluster nbextension enable --user`
И попытался запустить процесс следующим образом

```
from ipyparallel import Client
rc = Client()

res1 = rc[0].apply(get_data)
res2 = rc[1].apply(animation)

res1.get()
res2.get()
```

Вроде как оно пытается выполниться, но все равно выдает ошибку

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)<string> in <module>
<ipython-input-4-e2b3ae0513f5> in get_data()
NameError: name 'x_ind' is not defined
```

Как я понимаю, ipyparallel работает, только если в функции инкапсулированно описание абсолютно всех переменных и функций, если таковые используются.
Опять же, это игрушечный пример, который я попытался написать на основе своей основной программы. Там чуть больше глобальных переменных и сами функции более громоздкие.
Мне бы хотелось понять, как можно реализовать параллельное выполнение таких громоздких функций в юпитере.

Comment: Процессы копируют ваши данные и выполняются отдельно, напрямую данные из одного процесса в другом недоступны. Попробуйте потоки `Thread`.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь отпилить топором. Это возможно, но сложно. Jupyter предназначен для интерактивного исполнения многошаговых скриптов и экспериментов. Он в принципе не предназначался для обработки чего бы то ни было в фоне или в реальном времени. Вы выбрали не тот инструмент.